# Synergy doesn't seem to work on OS X Lion?

Tags: keyboard, osx-lion, synergy

I have been using synergy with my old mac mini running snow leopard perfectly for a while now.  Today I bought a new Mac-mini with Os X Lion.

Synergy doesn't seem to work. The old version will install but wont turn on.  The Newest version on the site seems not to install at all.

Does anyone know if this can be got to work, or when an update is likely?

Comment: Synergy 1.3.7 [should work](http://roaringapps.com/app:938). How does is "not install"? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I think I tried 1.4.3 I didnt see the beta label.  I'll try 1.3.7 and see if it works any better.  QSynergy wouldnt install when I double clicked on it.  I'll give further details when I try again.

Comment: If it helps, I'm using the SynergyKM client on OS X 10.7, which is successfully connecting to a standard synergy 1.4.3 beta server on Windows 7 x64...

Comment: Downgrading to Synergy 1.3.6 and using QSynergy solved my keyboard problems, and is working great with OSX Lion and Windows 7.

Comment: @huminuh83, you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QuickSynergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/) on Lion, SynergyKM on Snow Leopard and the usual installer on Windows machines.

[This even takes care of the modifier key problems. Wrote about this here.](http://journal.kaush.co/34/get-synergy-working-with-os-x-lion-including-modifier-keys)

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far. Thanks

Comment: Cheers sir, glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Synergy doesn't work very well on Lion, but you can get basic functionality by using the binaries and manually creating the conf file.  I wrote up a short tutorial here: http://cantus.us/tutorials/using-synergy-with-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: your link is dead, says it cant connect to the database. i was hoping to read your tutorial :(